# Azure DevOps: Can't set ':' symbol into BuildNumber field

Tags: azure-devops

Triyng to set Build number format in the build options page, but getting error, that ':' character is not allowed.
Is there something new about build variables, or it's just a bug?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cJDz.png)

Comment: Btw everything is good if I set the Build number via yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something new about build variables, or it's just a bug?

You should use **`$(Date:yyyyMMdd)`** instead of `($Date:yyyyMMdd)`.

The dollar sign `$` should be outside the brackets. You may not notice this small spelling mistake.

[image]

Check the document [Build number format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tokens) for some more details:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Oops, mistyped.

Answer (score 1):

well, the error clearly says `:` is forbidden from the UI. so its a UI limitation